# Derivation of the variance of the sampling distribution of the mean - one unclear sentence in an explanation

Tags: variance

From [OnlineStatBook](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/sampling_distributions/samp_dist_mean.html):

[image]

I don't understand the meaning of

> **Since the mean is $\frac{1}{N}$ times the sum, the variance of the sampling distribution of the mean would be $\frac{1}{N^2}$ times the variance of the sum**, which equals $\frac{σ^2}{N}$.

I only recently started refreshing my knowledge of statistics, and this sentence stumps me. I understand that the mean of any set of measurements is 1/N, but why does it appear squared here?

Comment: I added a derivation of the issue you brought up in your comment. Does it help?

Comment: @AntoniParellada - thank you! I'll read up on expected value and on the properties of variance some more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this can summarized by noting that $\text{Var}(cX)=c^2\text{Var}(X)$.

The $1/N$ in the mean, ends up outside the variance parenthesis as $1/N^2$.

So

$$\text{Var}\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right]=\frac{1}{N^2}\text{Var}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right]\underset{\small\begin{matrix}by\\variance\\sum \,law\end{matrix}}{=}\frac{1}{N^2}N\sigma^2=\frac{1}{N}\sigma^2$$

---

Following up on the first comment:

\begin{align}\text{Var}[cX]&=\mathbb E\left[\left(cX-\mathbb E[cX]\right)^2\right]\\&=\mathbb E\left[\left(cX-c \,\mathbb E(X)\right)^2\right]\\&=c^2\, \mathbb E\left[(X-\mathbb E(X))^2\right]\\&=c^2\text{Var}(X).\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand why  $\text{Var}(cX)=c^2\text{Var}(X)$. Maybe I should read more about the properties of variance. The answer by Syd Amerikaner is much more incomprehensible to me though.

Comment: @CopperKettle Check [variance properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties).

Comment: You could take this second-order homogeneity as a *defining property* of variance.  Up to multiplication by some universal constant, I believe the variance is *the only property* of distributions that enjoys this scaling relationship as well as being additive for independent variables (that is, $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ for any independent variables $X$ and $Y$). That is why it plays a distinguished role in the Central Limit Theorem, btw.

Comment: The variance is in squared units so if you multiply the values by $c$ the variance is multiplied by $c^2$.

Comment: @AntoniParellada This is very well done!

Answer (score 1):

The sample $X_1,\dots,X_n$ of size $n$ is assumed to be iid (idependent and identically distributed) with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, i.e. $E(X_i) = \mu$ for every $i$ and $V(X_i) = \sigma^2$.
Consider the sample mean $$\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$
Expected value of that term is given by $$E(\bar X) = E\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) = \frac{n}{n}\mu = \mu$$
where it was used that $E$ is linear (hence constant and sum can be taken out of the expectation) and that every $X_i$ has the same mean $\mu$.

The variance of the sample mean can be calculated similarily:
$$V(\bar X) = V\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^nV(X_i) = \frac{n}{n^2}\sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.$$
The variance acts a little different than expecation though. The variance is not linear in its argument but homogen of degree 2, i.e. $V(aX) = a^2V(X)$. Furthermore, the variance of a sum of random variable is only the sum of variances if the random variables are pairwise uncorrelated (i.e. in particular if the random variables are independent).

I recommend going through the steps I provided and ask if there remains something unclear.

By the way, the sentence you don't understand the meaning of is not quite correct either as it asserts that the variance of a sum of random variables is the sum of random variables (times $1/n^2$). But as I stated this is only correct in the case of pairwise uncorrelated, or even stronger, idependent random variables.

Comment: General form for Var(X+Y)=Var(X) +Var(Y) + 2 Cov (X, Y).  So @SydAmerikaner you are right to see the flaw in the "variance sum law". It holds only if Cov(X,Y)=0 which means X and Y are uncorrelated. Pairwise uncorrelated as you say.Your answer is right.  I might quibble a little with your english and you more or less stated the rule that Var(cX)=c^2 Var(X) without proof. But I like that you read the question carefully enough to catch the error.